# pattern regex for apache rewrite rule

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have the following pattern on a few thousand lines I will like to use regex to convert to what I want

```
RewriteRule ^/omg/deadly-venom/?$ http://www.example.com/omg/deadly-venom [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/buzz/get-on-it/?$ http://www.example.com/buzz/get-on-it/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

and others like this for a few thousand lines

So basically I want to have this

```
RewriteRule ^/omg/(deadly-venom)/?$ http://www.example.com/omg/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/buzz/(get-on-it)/?$ http://www.example.com/buzz/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

How do I achieve this? 
I use the sublime text editor but can also use sed or awk in terminal.

UPDATED: the last `/` should not result in double slash before the `$1` like this `//$1` instead it should still be `/$1` just look at the before and after from above and see lines with ending `/` and the one without

Comment: Looks like a simple sed 's/ [/$1 [/' might work...

Comment: not working..you sure thats the correct syntax? also can you add as answer instead of comment? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
sed -E 's|(.*/)([^/]*)(/\?\$.*)\2/{,1}|\1(\2)\3$1|' infile
```

The 2nd group captures the string/pattern that has to be enclosed in `(...)`, the 3rd group captures everything that follows up to the same string (backreferenced with `\2` in the LHS) which may have a trailing slash. So, basically, this replaces `\1\2\3\2{0 or 1 slash}` with `\1(\2)\3$1`.
If your `sed` doesn't support extended regex via `-E`:

```
sed 's|\(.*/\)\([^/]*\)\(/?\$.*\)\2/\{,1\}|\1(\2)\3$1|' infile
```